# Ending Linux scripts?

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I'm working on a script to manage some stuff on my server and I'm trying to figure out how I can close my script when I'm done with it. I open it using &, but how can I kill it with another script? I'm trying to do this programmatically but I'm very unfamiliar with Linux.

Comment: Propik, please add a snippit from your script (or just a summary) so other users can help you detect what the problem could be. This way it's not really a question, just a guess

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're asking. A properly written script should end on its own when it is done executing.

Comment: This should have been a comment

Comment: @Ivo - I disagree, the answer is "A properly written script should end on its own when it is done executing."

Comment: if so than this isn't a real question, because it's obviously flawed. Furthermore, this answer doesn't help propik solve his problem one bit, even though you're right

Comment: @Ivo - I agree, but without him editing his question to provide the script there is no way for me to tell him why his end-condition isn't being met. Any other solution is just a band-aid.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you have a script that you run in the background using & and you would like to kill it after a while. Also hopefully this script is supposed to be running for a while.

You can find the process id of you script by using a command such as:

```
ps  aux | grep test.sh| awk '{print $2}'
```

replace test.sh by the name of your script

to kill it run

```
kill `ps  aux | grep test.sh| awk '{print $2}'`
```

ps is the command to list the processes on the computer, aux says print every process on the system, grep search for a string from standard input (the output of ps in this case), awk is a program that allows you to process some text and run stuff on it. In this case I asked it to print the second column of the ouput of the first two commands.

Comment: This would also kill other processes that had the grepped string such as `vi test.sh`. Unless you do `grep -v grep` or `grep [t]est.sh`, the PID of the `grep` command will be included. Take a look at `pkill`. It lets you restrict selected processes by username and other criteria and only looks at the command name and not its arguments (unless you tell it to).